# How do I best protect my hardwood floors from damage by moving chair legs

Tags: floor, protection

I have beautiful oak wood floors in my kitchen. Its looking wonderful since I finally found something great to clean it with.

The problem I have though is an ongoing one. I have wood kitchen chairs and the pad things don''t stay on very well. I use felt pads that won''t stay stuck to the bottoms of the chairs. I am constantly having to go to home depot and buy new pads and even then they don''t stay on very well. They slide around the bottom and leave sticky gooey mess on my wood floors (from the adhesive on the felt pads to stick to the chair.

I tired the kind of pads that you nail on and nailed them on all 6 of my chairs and they were leavig white marks on my floors so I had to spend an evening prying them off my chairs with pliers.

Why am I having such a hard time finding something to put on the bottom of my wood chairs that won''t scratch my wood floor?

I can't do a rug because with 4 kids I end of with lots of food on the floor!

What's you guys' suggestion to protect my floors?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are Teflon glides that can be screwed on. You might try those on one chair to see how they work out for you. Because they screw on, then can be easily unscrewed. I would drill a pilot hole - though your existing nail holes might suffice.

[image: Teflon glides]

Teflon is a proprietary name for PTFE, so search also for screw-on PTFE furniture glides.

Teflon is slippery, so a disadvantage may be that your chairs might scoot away from you if you are not careful when sitting down. There's no getting away from the fact that staying-put requires friction which means abrasion.

Answer (score 0):

Felt is still your best bet.  Try using a swivel glide that sits level on the floor.  GlideGuys Furniture Glides attach easily and have snap on bases that can be replaced if worn or dirty without replacing the entire glide.  Felts are permanently attached and are made in USA.